# Can a non-constant holomorphic function take a line to a point?

Tags: complex-analysis

Title is pretty self explanatory, but given a function $f:D \to \mathbb{C}$, where $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ an open disk containing $0$ upon which $f$ is holomorphic, is it possible for $f(x) \equiv C$ for all $x \in D \cap \mathbb{R}$?

Edit:  Obviously this question is meaningful only if $f$ is non-constant on $D$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; by the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) $f$ cannot differ from the constant function $C$.

Comment: Note that this needs the stronger version of the identity theorem - that if $f, g$ agree on a set with an accumulation point in $D$, then $f=g$.

Answer (score 0):

you may assume that the line is the $x$-axis,  write $h(x,y)=f(x,y)+ig(x,y)$, you have $h(x,0)=f(x,0)+ig(x,0)$ is constant. This implies that $\partial_xf(x,0)=\partial_yg(x,0)=0$ The Cauchy Riemann equations give

$\partial_xf(x,0)=\partial_yg(x,0)$ and $\partial_yf(x,0)=-\partial_xg(x,0)$, this implies that $\partial_yg(x,0)=\partial_yf(x,0)=0$. This implies that the differential of $h$ is $0$ on the $x$-axis. You can repeat the argument to the holomorphic function $dh$,... and deduce that $d^nh(x,0)=0$. This implies that the Laurent serie at a point of the $x$-axis is zero. This implies that $f$ is constant in a neighborhood of a point of a $x$-axis, and henceforth is constant.